# Django Rest Framework - Serializer error when trying to add model from json with 1 attribute as array

Tags: rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Im trying to create an API with Django RestFramework to save some info of computers.

I have encountered a problem when the json has an attribute that is an array of IPv4 field.

I generated the following code

**Model**

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    os_system = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    
class ComputerIPAddress(models.Model):
    computer = models.ForeignKey(Computer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

**Serializer**

```
class ComputerIPAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComputerIPAddress
        fields = ('__all__')

class ComputerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ip_address = ComputerIPAddressSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        fields = ('__all__')
```

**Viewset**

```
class ComputerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Computer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ComputerSerializer

class ComputerIPAddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ComputerIPAddress.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ComputerIPAddressSerializer
```

The idea is that the IP belongs to the computer (if the computer is deleted, I am not interested in having the IP) and a computer can have several IP assigned to it.

The json that is sent is the following:

```
{'hostname':'PC-01','os_system':'Windows 10','ip_address':['192.168.1.10','192.168.2.10']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by overriding the create method the `ComputerSerializer`

```
class ComputerSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   ...
   def create(self, validated_data):
       ip_address = validated_data.pop("ip_address", None)
       computer = Computer.objects.create(**validated_data)

       if ip_address:
           for ip in ip_address:
               computer.computeripaddress_set.create(ip)

       return computer
```